# Is this question too vague for the main site?

Tags: discussion

This sounds vague, because it can have many, many possible answers (I hope), but I will accept any of them.

Basically, I want to demo a product to a company in Singapore, which has an eInk display (plus WiFi and BlueTooth):

[image]

To give them an idea of how it can be used to display their data, I would like to display some Singaporean data, maybe population, or similar.

The catch is that I want it to updated every second or so, displaying the temperature wouldn't be much good as it rarely varies.

I don't care what the data is, so is it on topic to ask for some Singaporean data which changes every second or so and has a gratis HTTP(S) API? I would like something to grab their attention and get them wondering how we can use [this (cheap) device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000133121789.html).

Comment: [link to question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15859/1511)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems on topic, especially if you ask for open data related to singapore and updating frequently

my 2 cents, simulate data, at least as a backup. to avoid the [demo effect](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=demo%20effect). for example, take the current population and simulate its increase with an estimate birth rate.

Comment: But, but, but ... that would be ... cheating ! (BSEG) Thanks & upvote